# Angular How to use *ngIf and *ngFor on same Html element

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a set of records displaying,instead of hidden i want to use *ngIf but if i write *ngIf it says error cant use ngIf and ngFor on same element.

```
<scx-indv-supplier
          class="row"
          *ngFor="let request of suppliers"
          [hidden]="request.status === 'CANCELLED' &&  request.durationDays > 179"
          [request]="request"
          [requestId]="request.requestId"
        >
</scx-indv-supplier>
```

But if use a div on top of scx-indv-supplier and write like this.It  throws a error Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

```
<div *ngIf="request.status != 'CANCELLED' &&  request.durationDays > 179">
    <scx-indv-supplier
    class="row"
    *ngFor="let request of suppliers"
    [request]="request"
    [requestId]="request.requestId"
  ></scx-indv-supplier>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-container tag here, like below

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let request of suppliers" >
<div>
<scx-indv-supplier
    class="row"
    *ngIf="request.status != 'CANCELLED' &&  request.durationDays > 179"
    [request]="request"
    [requestId]="request.requestId"
  ></scx-indv-supplier>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

As you cannot reference you request variable outside for loop scope

Comment: Hi Kishore now it does not display any records i think my ngIf is wrong

Comment: How to convert  [hidden]="request.status === 'CANCELLED' &&  request.durationDays > 179" to ngIf        please help sir

Comment: @nickolas you should check your if condition then

Comment: How to convert [hidden]="request.status === 'CANCELLED' && request.durationDays > 179" to ngIf please help sir

Comment: the conversion of [hidden] to *ngIf is wrong [hidden]="request.status === 'CANCELLED' && request.durationDays > 179"  how to write this in *ngIf way

Comment: @nickolas what do you mean by [hidden] to *ngIf conversion? can you elaborate, please?

Comment: i mean how to write that hidden statement in ngIf

Comment: *ngIf="request.status != 'CANCELLED' && request.durationDays > 179" this hides all records with APPROVED status also , i just want to hide records with cancelled status and date created with 180 days ago

Comment: when it satisfies both conditions "request.status != 'CANCELLED' && request.durationDays > 179" then the records should be removed from DOM

Comment: try *ngIf="!(request.status === 'CANCELLED' && request.durationDays > 179)"

Comment: excellent it worked Luqmaan thanks kishore and Luqmaan

Answer (score 1):

The answer is posted in official documentation regarding [Structural Directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#one-structural-directive-per-host-element)

> Someday you'll want to repeat a block of HTML but only when a
> particular condition is true. You'll try to put both an *ngFor and an
> *ngIf on the same host element. Angular won't let you. You may apply only one structural directive to an element.
>
> The reason is simplicity. Structural directives can do complex things
> with the host element and its descendents. When two directives lay
> claim to the same host element, which one takes precedence? Which
> should go first, the NgIf or the NgFor? Can the NgIf cancel the effect
> of the NgFor? If so (and it seems like it should be so), how should
> Angular generalize the ability to cancel for other structural
> directives?
>
> There are no easy answers to these questions. Prohibiting multiple
> structural directives makes them moot. There's an easy solution for
> this use case: put the *ngIf on a container element that wraps the
> *ngFor element. One or both elements can be an ng-container so you don't have to introduce extra levels of HTML.

Comment: That's it. I have components with dynamic parameters and many problems when using various conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the error also tells you what's the solution.

In this case, you must use `ng-template` to wrap your `*ngFor`:

```
  <ng-template *ngFor="let request of suppliers"
    <scx-indv-supplier
      class="row"
      [hidden]="request.status === 'CANCELLED' &&  request.durationDays > 179"
      [request]="request"
      [requestId]="request.requestId"
     >
     </scx-indv-supplier>
   </ng-template>
```

Comment: i want to remove   [hidden]="request.status === 'CANCELLED' &&  request.durationDays > 179" and add *ngIf="request.status != 'CANCELLED' &&  request.durationDays > 179" where to add that ngIf please help sir